# Unable to record script using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and unable to record script using Jmeter. Eventhough I have followed the instruction provided by Apache.Jmeter.org. Pls update me with the few esay steps to move on.

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: I have tried all the information you have metioned here. But it wont work. Still unable to record the script. I need to work only on IE alone. Steps I have followed is, 1. Lanched Jemeter; 2. Cretae Thread Group; 3. HTTP Request Defaults; 4. updated server name/IP and port no; 5. Added Recording Controller; 6. Under Workbench created HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder; 7. Updated URL patterns .*\.html; 8. Added View Result Tree. 9. Clicked on Start and install Roor CA certificate; 10. Launched my application and moved on some modules; 11. Finally I have did not see any script that has been recorded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are recording the script you can follow sequence,

1. Jmeter becomes your proxy and records everything between your real proxy and you so make proxy as localhost and port no as 8080 for http
2. if you are trying record a script for application running on proxy/local machine then above setup is enough
3. if you want to record script for a application on WAN then start jmeter like,

   Jmeter - H "proxy which you are using" -P "port no" <-u "username" -a "password">
4. by default test plan is present when you start jmeter
5. add threadgroup and proxy recorder in script
6. start recording

Answer (score 1):

If you have difficulties in setting up HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (despite the fact it's perfectly documented in [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide you could try using [Google Chrome JMeter plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which allows JMeter scripts recording right from browser without needing to worry about proxies, browser extra configuration, SSL certificates, etc.

The most common error for using JMeter proxy is `Do not use proxy for localhost / 127.0.0.1`. If you have this or similar option in your browser make sure that it's **disabled**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but the links are in spanish

- http://josepablosarco.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/performance-testing-con-jmeter-paso-por-paso-para-grabar-escenarios/
- http://carloszuluaga.wikidot.com/pruebascarga:grabar-script-web